# Geting net.tcp not supported when adding service reference

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, wcf-endpoint

i have hosted my WCF service in IIS and have following endpoints configured

> ```
>     <endpoint name="MainService" contract="Docs.ICalculatorService" address="http://localhost:49495/WcfService1/service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding">
>             </endpoint>
>     <endpoint name="MainTcpService"  contract="Docs.ICalculatorService" address="net.tcp://localhost:49496/WcfService1/service.svc" binding="netTcpBinding">
>    </endpoint>
> ```

i have hosted my WCF service on port no 49495 which is real ,
now i have configured another endpoint which is using port no 49496 
do i need to host this WCF service on another port 49496 or i am missing something

getting this error when looked in stack trace

> The ChannelDispatcher at 'net.tcp://localhost:49495/WcfService1/service.svc' with contract(s) '"ICalculatorService"' is unable to open its IChannelListener

i have configured Endpoints and Configured Bindings in IIS 7
but now i am getting a new error

**You have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .Net Framing. It is possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint.****

Comment: I think we need more of your web.config.

Comment: Have you enabled non-HTTP service activation for IIS?

Comment: My Configuration contains two  end points and i am using IIS 7 and convigured both bindings http and net.tcp when i am using only http its working fine but when i include net.tcp, i am unable to get the meta data

Comment: Your service's web.config is not the problem. You need to [configure IIS to activate WCF services over TCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731053.aspx) and other non-HTTP protocols.

Answer (score 0):

As shabulator says, you need to enable the non-http service activator.
In case this isn't clear to anyone stumbling across this, this is a Windows feature you need to switch on.

On Windows 7 (Server 2008 will be similar) under Control Panel -> Programs you will see "Turn Windows features on or off". This brings up a dialog as the one shown.

[image: Windows Features dialog]

Under Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 tick the two boxes to install the features.

When I did this, it had the side effect of putting .NET 3.5 onto the server, which I didn't want as I was using a later version.
If this happens, open a command prompt and go to the .NET 4.0.30319 folder and run the aspnet regiis tool.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -iru